# Making an ipv6-only server reachable via ipv4

Tags: dns, ipv6, ipv4

I'm running a server at home, but I don't have an Ipv4. I bought a domain, and entered the ipv6 as AAAA record. Everything is fine, I can reach the server via ipv6, but is there any way I can make it reachable via ipv4 as well? All ISPs should have a way of accessing ipv6 networks nowadays, shouldn't they? Is there maybe some (preferably free) service that I can enter as my A (ipv4) record that will tunnel the request to ipv6?

Comment: why not try Cloudflare they offer IP6to4 proxy you just have to add one AAA record .

Comment: I am currently only having the problem when using ssh from my university to my home server. I am now just proxying through a VPS that I have anyway that has both ipv4 and ipv6 but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all ISPs deploy IPv6. Most of them do for most products, at least in Germany. However, not all users or admins have enabled IPv6 in their networks. So you can't expect universal IPv6 availability yet.

There are technologies that should make IPv6 addresses available on IPv4-only networks, but since they circumvent some firewall concepts, they're often blocked in company networks.

You can use socat on a host that has both IPv4 and IPv6, like a VPS somewhere. Use it like this (Assuming IPv4 address is 198.51.100.10, IPv6 address is 2001:db8::1a, protocol is TCP and port is 80):

`socat TCP4-LISTEN:198.51.100.0:80 TCP6:[2001:db8::1a]:80`

Comment: That would mean I couldn't use the ipv4 for anything else on port 80 right. So if I still wanted to run a webserver on the VPS I'd need to have a second ipv4

Comment: Yes and no. You can't use port 80 for anything else. You can set up an http server to listen on a different port, though.

Comment: If it really is about http/https, you could set up the machine with both IPv4 and IPv6 as a reverse proxy for the domain name in question.